# Getting two content type in header when i set content type to json

Tags: php

i want to set content type in the http header using php for which i have used the function as below :

```
header("HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST");
header("Content-Type : application/json;charset=utf-8",true);
```

the content type is set to application/json but the problem here is that i am also getting the `Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8` when i hit this on my postman.

actually i am getting two content type in my response on postman :

```
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type →application/json;charset=utf-8
```

Comment: The only advice we can give you is to do a backwards debug and find where that happens and why, nothing more

Answer (score 0):

You may use `header_remove('Content-Type')` to clear any previous headers that are being set by code somewhere. See this link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

But definitely you need to find out the root cause, that's sending the `Content-type: text/html`
Otherwise you may break your application

Comment: this not working for me still getting two content type  in response

Comment: Looks like the header is set to 'Content-type: text/html' after you have set your Content-type to json. You will have to track where it's set later in the application. Are you on some framework?